# How can i throw an object to a specific point with physics

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, throw

I want exactly this :

The probability of going to the basket must be 100%.

[Throw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEnsI.png)

I tried this :

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(pota.position.x - transform.position.x, pota.position.y - transform.position.y, pota.position.z - transform.position.z);
float vAngle = Vector3.Angle(direction, Vector3.forward);
float hAngle = Vector3.Angle(direction, Vector3.left);
float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pota.position);
float yDistance = Mathf.Abs(distance * Mathf.Cos(vAngle)) + 0.5f;
float xzDistance = (distance * Mathf.Sin(vAngle));
float xDistance = (xzDistance * Mathf.Sin(hAngle));
float zDistance = Mathf.Abs(xzDistance * Mathf.Cos(hAngle));                    
rb.AddForce(new Vector3(xDistance, yDistance, zDistance), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this is something VERY complicated and there is no real easy way to figure this one out

Read one of the answers in this quetion
and good luck figuring this out
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486775/how-do-you-calculate-the-trajectory-of-an-arrow

(or you could just use lurp or slurp or movetowards lel)

Comment: @absakalli np mate